# parameter for my average function, the error it writes is "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, methods, average

```
/*METODA MAIN*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    int m, n;
    int sloupec;
    float prumerSloupce;
    System.out.println("zadej pocet radku pole: ");
    m = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("zadej pocet sloupcu pole: ");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    int[][] a;
    /*NAPLNENI POLE NAHODNYMI CISLY*/
    a = naplnPole(m, n);
    /*TISKNUTI POLE*/
    tiskPole(a);
    System.out.println("Zadej cislo sloupce, jehoz prumer chces znat ");
    sloupec = sc.nextInt();
    prumerSloupce = aritmetickyPrumerSloupce(a, sloupec);

    /*METODA NAPLNENI POLE*/
    public static int[][] naplnPole(int m, int n) {
        int[][] x = new int[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                x[i][j] = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
            }
        }
        return x;
    } /*METODA TISKNUTI POLE*/
    public static void tiskPole(int[][] x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(x[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    /*METODA ZJISTENI ARITMETICKEHO PRUMERU SLOUPCE*/
    public static float aritmetickyPrumerSloupce(int[][] a, int sloupec) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        sum += array[i][sloupec];`this is the error line`
        return sum / (float) a.length;
    }
```

> Everything works except the method, i'm trying to get average of a column from a matrix that consist of random numbers. number of rows and columns is defined by typing from scanner.

Comment: Well what array do you want to take the average of? You haven't *got* an array as far as I can see...

Comment: You're feeding in a variable called `a` in your method call. What is it's value?

Comment: Where are`a`, `sc`, and `array` defined?

Comment: I guess, the compiler gives you the info, which symbol cannot be found, right ?

Comment: `sum += array[i][sloupec]; //this is the error line` ... mmhh .. you're using the array `a` everywhere, but `array` on this line. Now what could be the error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't defining your array `a` anywhere that I can see;

```
int[][] a = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
// ...
prumerSloupce = aritmetickyPrumerSloupce(a, column);
```

and your function should be using `a.length` like

```
public static float aritmetickyPrumerSloupce(int[][] a, int column) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        sum += a[i][column];
    return sum / (float) a.length;
}
```